# np.arange() function in python

Tags: python, numpy, random-forest

I am trying to make a random forest regression so I need to use np.arange()function but it give me an error .
the error occur when run this function:

```
X_val =np.arange(min(X_train), max(X_train), 0.01)
```

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncwHx.jpg)

This is my complete code:

```
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test =train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=0)
RFReg=RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=10,random_state=0)
RFReg.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_predict_rfr=RFReg.predict((X_test))
r_square =metrics.r2_score(y_test,y_predict_rfr)
X_val =np.arange(min(X_train), max(X_train), 0.01)
```

Comment: X_train have multiple columns? You might need to use numpy min instead of builtin min from python.  np.min(X_train), np.max(X_train)

Comment: The error is with min(x_train) and max(x_train)

Answer (score 1):

You may be getting this error? `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`

My advice is to use the below statement:-

```
X_val = np.arange(np.min(X_train).values, np.max(X_train).values, 0.01)
```

This won't include any string.